# Outlook offline, rest of PC online

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

One of my users has a weird problem. He's not aware of one specific thing that's changed to make it start.

Outlook, after he comes in from using his machine at home reads offline. It's not in Work Offline mode, the computer is online and other web services (inc other 365 services) are working fine.

If you try to add a new O365 account at the time, it states that the computer is offline.

At some point up to 4-5 hours after the issue first happens, it'll all come online as normal. He states it's fine once connected and it won't be an issue again.

I've tried:

- Defaulting any networking settings
- Restarting networking services whilst the issue is happening to try and bump it online
- New Outlook profile
- Repairing the Outlook install and installing fresh
- New Windows profile

Really don't actually know what to try other than this. Any ideas?

Comment: You could reset the router (followed by factory reset) and also temporarily disable the security software. Does reboot help? Is it happening when booting in Safe Mode with Network?

Comment: Really weird. As I know, simply adding email account will not influence the Internet states of windows. As @harrymc mentioned, maybe you could try window safe mode and check if the issue has any difference.

Comment: Are you using any VPN services? Issues might happen as well if the VPN services is enabled.

Comment: Can this issue be reproduced if you log in to your web mail client？

Comment: @harrymc security software disabled seems to make little difference, reboots apparently don't make any difference - though I will try it, I fear the issue is too sporadic to 100% prove in safe mode

Comment: @JeffYang7 VPN was my first inclination, though this particular user doesn't use it. Outlook's webmail will work just fine, it's just Outlook that's "offline" (but not in Work Offline mode) - the internet and other web based services are just fine, teams included!

Comment: Well, have you tried adding your email account via Control Panel > Mail > Email Accounts > New and then start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) to see if the issue has any difference there.